# Plot GPS coordinates

Tags: python, linux

My problem is to plot gps coordinates in real time onto a blank canvass and keep the most recent plot centered. The objective is to use a StrawberryPi and monitor in a tractor to maintain a view of the ground covered. No need for maps just a blank canvas.  I can already display real time lat long data using a GPSPoller thread and gpsd. I am stumped on how to plot the points and maintain them centered.

```
class GpsPoller(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    global gpsd #bring it in scope
    gpsd = gps(mode=WATCH_ENABLE) #starting the stream of info
    self.current_value = None
    self.running = True #setting the thread running to true

  def run(self):
    global gpsd
    while gpsp.running:
      gpsd.next() #this will continue to loop and grab EACH set of gpsd info to clear the buffer

if __name__ == '__main__':
  gpsp = GpsPoller() # create the thread
  try:
    gpsp.start() # start it up
    while True:


  os.system('clear')

  print
  print ' GPS reading'
  print '----------------------------------------'
  print 'latitude    ' , gpsd.fix.latitude
  print 'longitude   ' , gpsd.fix.longitude

  .......... etc
```

Thank you for the feedback. My problem is to identify a suitable technology that will enable me to plot points on a "canvas" and keep the "canvas" centered on the last point. The trace will enable me to follow a path on the ground and ensure full coverage of for example spreading fertiliser  which is actually quite tricky in practice. Spread width may be 12 m which I can emulate with the size of the plotted point. Distance and area covered are also easy to calculate. It is the visual guide that I am finding difficult to know where to start. Any help would be appreciated

I am familiar with Python and tkInter and more than willing to learn to do it myself if I could get a suitable starting point

Comment: I'm unclear on the problem you're seeing ... can you please elaborate on what behaviour you're seeing, and what the expected outcome is?

Comment: I don't see anything here that deals with plotting points (or anything else).  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you post some code on your previous attempts to plot the points?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated the question which better explains the problem